# Getting value of one to many relationship

Tags: sql-server

I have an employee table `emp` like this:

```
emp_id    emp_name   emp_role
______________________________
1          aaaa       Supervisor
2          bbbb       Supervisor
3          cccc       helper
4          dddd       helper
5          eeee       helper
6          ffff       helper
```

And another table `Supervisor` and helper mapping (`Sup_Helper_Map`):

```
supervisor_id      helper_id
____________________________
1                   3
1                   4
2                   5
2                   6
```

I want data in below structure in a single query if possible, for eg,.

```
Supervisor_id   Supervisor_name   helper_id        helper_name
_______________________________________________________________
1                 aaaa             3                 cccc
1                 aaaa             4                 dddd
2                 bbbb             5                 eeee
2                 bbbb             6                 ffff
```

Comment: helper is employer?

Comment: yes. helper also employer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply JOIN `Employee` table with 2 times to get your expected result.

Working Demo with the given sample data:

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE (emp_id  INT, emp_name VARCHAR (100), emp_role VARCHAR (100));

INSERT INTO @Employee (emp_id, emp_name, emp_role) VALUES
(1, 'aaaa', 'Supervisor'),
(2, 'bbbb', 'Supervisor'),
(3, 'cccc', 'helper'),
(4, 'dddd', 'helper'),
(5, 'eeee', 'helper'),
(6, 'ffff', 'helper');

DECLARE @Sup_Helper_Map TABLE (Supervisor_id  INT, Helper_id INT);

INSERT INTO @Sup_Helper_Map (Supervisor_id, Helper_id) VALUES
(1, 3),
(1, 4),
(2, 5),
(2, 6);

SELECT M1.Supervisor_id, E1.emp_name AS Supervisor_name, 
       M1.Helper_id, E2.emp_name AS Helper_name
FROM @Sup_Helper_Map M1
JOIN @Employee E1 ON E1.emp_id = M1.Supervisor_id
JOIN @Employee E2 ON E2.emp_id = M1.Helper_id
```

Result:

```
Supervisor_id   Supervisor_name Helper_id   Helper_name
--------------------------------------------------------
1               aaaa            3           cccc
1               aaaa            4           dddd
2               bbbb            5           eeee
2               bbbb            6           ffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    s.supervisor_id,
    e.emp_name supervisor_Name,
    s.helper_id,
    h.emp_name helper_name
FROM
    emp e INNER JOIN 
    Sup_Helper_Map s ON e.emp_id = s.supervisor_id INNER JOIN 
    emp h ON s.helper_id = h.emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        dbo.Sub_Helper_Map.supervisor_id, emp1_1.emp_name AS Supervisor_name, dbo.Sub_Helper_Map.helper_id, dbo.emp.emp_name AS helper_name
FROM            dbo.emp INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Sub_Helper_Map ON dbo.emp.emp_id = dbo.Sub_Helper_Map.helper_id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.emp AS emp1_1 ON dbo.Sub_Helper_Map.supervisor_id = emp1_1.emp_id
```